# Circular dependencies after upgrade react-scripts to version 5

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

I tried to upgrade react-scripts to 5.0.1 and my app can compile but just show empty page. I guess there might be circular dependencies. So I used the plugin circular-dependency-plugin to see if my repo contains this problem. It turned out emitting so many errors..

I am wondering why in react-scripts 4.x.x won't cause this problem?

I guess it because newest react-scripts use webpack 5 and it use esm directly?
The esm idea comes from the image below.
Any thoughts? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: what exactly is the issue which you are facing ?